# Let $S$ be a set of $k$ elements, where $k$ is a whole number. Suppose $n$ is not an element of $S$. Show that $S$ union s has $k + 1$ elements.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $S$ be a set of $k$ elements, where $$k \in \omega$$ Suppose $$n \notin S$$Show that $$S \cup \{n\}$$ has $k + 1$ elements.

I'm honestly last as to where I should start. I was thinking of maybe a contradiction that it wasn't $k + 1$ elements. I really just need a little idea of where to start the proof.

Answer (score 4):

Since $|S|=k$, there is a bijection $f:S\to\{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}$. Define a bijection $g:S\cup\{n\}\to\{0,1,\ldots, k-1,k\}$ as follows:

$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
f(x)&\text{if}&x\in S\\
k&\text{if}&x=n
\end{cases}
$$

Then, $g$ is a bijection since $n\notin S$, so $|S\cup \{n\}|=|\{0,1,\ldots,k-1,k\}|=k+1$.